# what is my error in the sum of power functions?

Tags: java, math, biginteger

I was solving this [problem6](http://www.cstutoringcenter.com/problems/problems.php?id=6), I dont even know the answer but, when I finished I think that I will get Ok, but my answers fails, 7910956276398901303 this is my answer **1303**, can you help me with this error, I dont understand what is wrong my logic , code??, Its just a simple power function

**Corrected**

this is the correct code

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Problema6 {

```
static BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);
static BigDecimal num = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int n = 2;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
        sum = sum.add(power(i, n));
        n++;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);

    String number = sum.toString();

    System.out.println(number.substring(number.length() - 4, number.length()));

}

public static BigDecimal power(int x, int y) {

    num = BigDecimal.valueOf(x).pow(y).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(y).pow(x));

    return num;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is with using `Math.pow(...)`. Switch to `BigDecimal.pow(...)` to avoid overflows

Comment: Its not about the code, it is the answer that I think that was correct but not, I dont know why my answer is wrong

Comment: Try using BigDecimal.pow(...) like I said. That's why the answer might be wrong

Comment: thanks for your help, I got accepted answer changing to BigDecimal all the code, but how did you find it?, thanks for all